# dotnet core 2.1+ System.Drawing.Common's grapic DrawImage loss transparency in linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm trying add watermark to a jpeg picture using dotnetcore's system.drawing.common@4.5, everything is ok at my pc development environment, but when it run at linux server, the image's quality loss.

```
string inputFile = "inputFile.jpg";
string waterMarkFile = "waterMark.png";
var wmImage = Image.FromFile(waterMarkFile);
FileInfo input = new FileInfo(inputFile);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var fs = input.OpenRead())
    {
        fs.CopyTo(stream);
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
            {
                using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(img))
                {
                    int initX = img.Width / 2;
                    int initY = img.Height / 2;
                    int wmWidth = img.Width * 0.1 > wmImage.Width ? (int)(img.Width * 0.1) : img.Width;
                    int wmHeight = (wmImage.Height * wmWidth) / wmImage.Width;
                    int offsetX = wmWidth / 2;
                    int offsetY = wmHeight / 2;
                    for (int x = initX; x < img.Width + wmWidth; x += (int)(wmWidth *  2.5))
                    {
                        for (int y = initY; y < img.Height + wmHeight; y += (int)(wmHeight * 2.5))
                        {
                            graphic.DrawImage(wmImage, x - offsetX, y - offsetY, wmWidth, wmHeight);
                            if (x != initX || y !=initY)
                            {
                                graphic.DrawImage(wmImage, initX - (x - initX) - offsetX , y - offsetY, wmWidth, wmHeight);
                                graphic.DrawImage(wmImage, initX - (x - initX) - offsetX, initY - (y - initY) - offsetY, wmWidth, wmHeight);
                                graphic.DrawImage(wmImage, x - offsetX, initY - (y - initY) - offsetY, wmWidth, wmHeight);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    img.Save($"wm_{inputFile}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
wmImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: The image output in Linux Server: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14BIZoF7QWwN7IsIBAx0fsidzzyK6B0BL/view?usp=sharing), and in my PC:[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ZQfrBgj5yJXghyokPHyUNT1fGCA3On3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What happens if you just paint both of the images onto a _new_ 32bpp image instead, and then just save that as jpeg?

Comment: I'v resolved it by moved those codes from docker to my server local environment. the docker i used is mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime@2.1.13-alpine3.9 & install the libgdiplus. it might was the libgdiplus for alpine's compatibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem still exists. I had the same problem with Debian based aspnet core images (3.1-buster-slim, 5.0-buster-slim). It looks like an old version of libgdiplus will be installed here. To run the app on the local environment is no solution for me (everythings has to run on kubernetes pods...)

I found two solutions:

1. Use Ubuntu based images (3.1-focal, 5.0-focal)
2. Use Debian (buster-slim) image, clone current libgdiplus form github an compile inside the image.

I created Dockerfiles for both scenarios and published a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/jugstalt/docker-images):

Comment: i move my program out from docker container and run my program on my serve, then everything be ok! i think the problem was the offical donetcore runtime docker image used a old version libgdiplus

Comment: `-focal` helped me with a headless chrome/pdf-gen application. libgdiplus seems broken on the standard Debian based images. Thanks man!